# how to pass a dynamic variable from one function to another in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, eventtrigger

Google sheets link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oF_fM545_Vl_gCaliERs3bVjCfpz5oROstD_ndQAkjE/edit?usp=sharing

Google forms link: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfom_KlWTWvPQDZF5mO4YTgwkznnB0LykMXibDrpfc-JBh-OA/viewform

App script link: https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1uyj_Fm9yNePkUTiuvc-cdwkxPNZJwGPHMEig9-1Ufn01JWPZvZynfcxk/edit

Im getting an object Object when declaring a variable in the second function and consequently a null value when extracting the script properties.

The code currently:

1. runs upon a form submission
2. extracts the timestamp from the response as well as the email question
3. stores in the script properties the timestamp property with the email value
4. creates a time based trigger to run the `firstLetter` function

The problem comes in the `firstLetter` function, as the `Logger.log(propertyKey)` returns `timestamp_[object Object]` and the `Logger.log(email)` returns `null`. I believe its because the firstLetter function isnt getting the timestamp variable, which really has to do with Javascript scoping restrictions.

But I need the `firstLetter` function to run after the `formResponse` function (that is whay I created the trigger) and I need timestamp to be dynamic (not sure if thats the correct way to say it) but what I mean is I need the firstLetter function to only extract the script property from the corresponding response it was triggered by because multiple people can be submitting form responses.

Here is the code:

```
function formResponse(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var email = e.values[1];

  var propertyKey = 'timestamp_' + timestamp;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(propertyKey, email);

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('firstLetter')
  .timeBased()
  .after(10000)
  .create();
}

function firstLetter(timestamp) {
  var propertyKey = 'timestamp_' + timestamp;
  Logger.log(propertyKey)
  var email = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(propertyKey);
  Logger.log(email)

  if (email) {
    var firstL = email.charAt(0);

    Logger.log('First letter of email: ' + firstL);

    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty(propertyKey);
  } else {
    Logger.log('Email not found for the given timestamp.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [dummy sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can further help you.

Comment: The parameter in firstLetter will be filled with the event object of the trigger not the timestamp

Comment: You can’t pass a parameter with a trigger. Just read it directly from Script properties.

Comment: @cnavar I added the corresponding links. Please let me know if i should provide with more information.

Comment: @Cooper thank you for you reply, but I dont understand what you mean by reading it directly from Script properties. Could you ellaborate on your comment?

Comment: @S Inversin Social y Alianzas E I have posted an answer to your question. Kindly test the code and let me know how it went.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384141/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function formResponse(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var email = e.values[1];

  var propertyKey = 'timestamp_' + timestamp;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(propertyKey, email);

  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  firstLetter(propertyKey);
}

function firstLetter(propertyKey) {
  Logger.log(propertyKey)
  var email = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(propertyKey);
  Logger.log(email)

  if (email) {
    var firstL = email.charAt(0);

    Logger.log('First letter of email: ' + firstL);

    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty(propertyKey);
  } else {
    Logger.log('Email not found for the given timestamp.');
  }
}
```

I used `Utilities.sleep` to ensure that the `firstLetter` will only run after 10 seconds. Here's the result after testing this code:

[image]

Comment: Hello @cnavar thank you for providing an answer. It did process correctly but I didnt explain enough why i added a trigger. The reason I added it is so that the firstLetter function runs separately so I dont exceed the 6 min. max. run time. I know the code i provided is short, but it is for an example of a code i have that takes longer.

Comment: Hello @S Inversin Social y Alianzas E, I'm glad that the problem you described on your post was adressed by my answer. However, with respect to your follow up question, I'm afraid that it already counts as another question / post. I recommend that you post it as a new question that includes your whole code so that the community can replicate the issue with regards to the max 6 mins runtime.